# typedef, can't find error in two functions

Tags: c, function, struct

I was trying to make a program in C that would allow me to store some information about students. The idea was to make a new data type, then use it to create a few functions to manipulate the data. In particular at one point I had to find the oldest student in a group and then print out its details using another functions. The function I made that is supposed to find the maximum age in the group doesn't work. can anybody find the mistake? In particular the functions that don't work i think are calcmax and find. there are ano bugs, but when i call calcmax in main and try to print the result some random number appears and that's it. I think there is a problem with the logic in one of the loops, but I can't find it. Thanks a lot.

```
typedef struct{
char f[MAXIM];
char s[MAXIM];
char id[MAXIM];
char dep[MAXIM];
char g;
int age;
}student_t;

student_t mkstud(char first[],char sec[], char idn [],char de[], char sex, int eta){
student_t person;
strcpy(person.f,first);
strcpy(person.s,sec);
strcpy(person.id,idn);
strcpy(person.dep,de);
person.g = sex;
person.g = eta;
return person;
}

student_t scstud(){
char first[MAXIM],sec[MAXIM],idn[MAXIM],de[MAXIM];
char sex;
int eta;
student_t person;
printf("name ");
scanf("%s",first);
printf("surname ");
scanf("%s",sec);
printf("id ");
scanf("%s", idn);
printf("depart ");
scanf("%s",de);
printf("sex ");
scanf(" %c",&sex);
printf("age ");
scanf(" %d", &eta);
person= mkstud(first,sec,idn,de,sex,eta);
return person;
}


int calcmax(student_t *class, int length){
int diff,i;
int max[MAXIM];
diff=class[0].age-class[1].age;
if(diff>=0){
    max[0]=class[0].age;
}
else if(diff<0){
    max[0]=class[1].age;
}
max[1]=max[0];
for (i=0;i<length;i++){
    if (max[i]>=class[i+1].age){
        max[i+1]=max[i];
    }
    else if(max[i]<class[i+1].age){
        max[i+1]=class[i+1].age;
    }

}
    return max[length];
}
void printdetails(student_t std){
printf("name: %s",std.f);
printf("surname: %s",std.s);
printf("ID: %s",std.id);
printf("department: %s",std.dep);
printf("gender: %c",std.g);
printf("age: %d",std.age);
}

/*void find(student_t *class, int length){
int std,i;
std = calcmax(class, length);
for(i=0;i<=length-1;i++){
    if (std==class[i].age) {
         printdetails(class[i]);
    }

}
}*/
int main(void){
int i,j;
student_t class[6];
class[0]= mkstud("John","Bishop","s1234","inf", 'm',18);
class[1]=mkstud("Lady","Cook","s2345","Eng",'f',21);
class[2]=mkstud("James","Jackson","s3456","Eng",'m',17);
for(i=4;i<=6;i++){
    printf(" student %d \n", i);
    class[i-1]=scstud();
}
j=calcmax(class, 6);
printf("%d", j);


/*find(class, 3);*/
return EXIT_SUCCESS;}
```

Comment: What do you get as the max result when calculating the max of `class[0]`, `class[1]`, and `class[2]`? Break the problem down to make it easier to find the mistake. Use `printf` in the max calculation function to "see" what it's doing or step though it with the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems I see:

1. Minor error in `mkstud`. You are assigning both gender and age to the `g` member of the struct.

   ```
   person.g = sex;
   person.g = eta;
   ```

   That should be:

   ```
   person.g = sex;
   person.age = eta;
   ```
2. You have not initialized the array `max` in `calcmax`.
3. Your logic in `calcmax` is flawed. If you add `printf` statements in the right places, you'll be able to see that `max[length]` is assigned an incorrect value.

   ```
   int calcmax(student_t *class, int length){
      int diff,i;
      int max[MAXIM] = {0};
      diff=class[0].age-class[1].age;
      if(diff>=0){
         max[0]=class[0].age;
      }
      else if(diff<0){
         max[0]=class[1].age;
      }
      max[1]=max[0];

      // ADDED
      printf("max[0]: %d\n", max[0]);
      printf("max[1]: %d\n", max[1]);

      for (i=0;i<length;i++){
         if (max[i]>=class[i+1].age){
            max[i+1]=max[i];

            // ADDED
            printf("max[%d]: %d\n", i+1, max[i+1]);
         }
         else if(max[i]<class[i+1].age){
            max[i+1]=class[i+1].age;

            // ADDED
            printf("max[%d]: %d\n", i+1, max[i+1]);
         }
      }

      // ADDED
      printf("max[%d]: %d\n", length, max[length]);
      return max[length];
   }
   ```

   You can try fix that rather complex function but it can be simplified.

   ```
   int calcmax(student_t *class, int length){

      if ( length <= 0 )
      {
         return -1;
      }

      int max = class[0].age;
      for (int i = 1; i < length; ++i )
      {
         if ( max < class[i].age )
         {
            max = class[i].age;
         }
      }
      return max;
   }
   ```

Comment: Hi, i have a couple of questions: what does the return -1 do? and second, what does the compiler do in your loop if max>class[i]? does it just repeat the loop? because basically the only reason why i made max an array is that i wanted to be able to assign it its previous value if it was > than class[i]. if your loop repeats, without the second if statement, then i didn't even need to use max as an array

Comment: @MicheleGalli, the `return -1;` just returns `-1` from the function if `length` is equal to `0`. As for the loop, if my simplified version does not make sense, I recommend that you should spend some time working through the basics of the language, using a textbook or an online tutorial.

Comment: i did simplify the function in the end, and it is essentially identical to the one you wrote, but i didn't put the first if statement. because length is supposed to be the length of the array.

Comment: @MicheleGalli, I am glad to hear things worked out for you.